# Explanation of the hadoop file system

Tags: hadoop

Can any one help me understand the data storage concept of hadoop?

As I understand it, hadoop deals with fs image and data blocks, and fsimage and edit logs paths are stored hdfs-site.xml. But what about the data blocks? Can anyone help me in this? I am little bit confused where the /user and /tmp dir is actually present in the filesystem.

I used this link to set up a single node hadoop cluster: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files are split into blocks and stored in the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). Consult the [HDFS module](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html) of Yahoo's [Hadoop Tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/index.html) for a description of HDFS. The directories stored in HDFS can be viewed by typing the following command into a terminal: `hadoop dfs -ls`

Comment: hey leonard first of all thnx a lot and i just wants to know where actaully the file are stored i know they are in HDFS but ther must be present under / or i am wrong ?

Comment: If you're asking if HDFS files are accessible from outside of Hadoop, the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you leonard now i under stand it

Comment: You're quite welcome. If this has sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as best answer to help anyone else that may have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The Namenode's FSImage keeps track of which Datanode has which files.  In the hdfs-site.xml file, the configuration 'dfs.data.dir' defines where the datanode stores the underlying files on the filesystem.  This can be a comma separated list of directories (think multiple disks).